# Sharepoint - How to remove link from Javascript form within List

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, list, hyperlink

We have a sharepoint Aspx form that is formatted like an excel spreadsheet.  On each row of the form are links that when clicked, launch a script to show new links, allowing the user to add, view, or hide comments.  This will appear for each line item clicked on.

We would like to remove the "add comment" link from the script, but cannot find anywhere to do so in both Sharepoint or Sharepoint Designer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavasScript to remove any HTML element, you just need to be able to target it.

See [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) & [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) for targeting
and then [Node.removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild) for deleting it from the document.

Answer (score 0):

to remove it via the client side, yes you could try some JS or CSS but you find it hard finding a unique handle. Firebug will help to see if one is available. But chances are you need to take a look at the Schema.xml

you can find this by using Sharepoint Manager http://www.codeplex.com/spm

alternativly look in the onet.xml